# Karma highlight on subscribe

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Here is my Component code. I am trying to achieve full code coverage but fourth line was getting highlighted `res => { this.days = res`.

Here is the code added for Details service

```
constructor(public detailsService:DashboardService ) {
   this.csvContent = '';
}

public getNonDealingDates() {
  try {
    this.detailsService.nonDealingdates().subscribe(
      res => { this.days = res },
      error => { throw error; }
    );
  } catch(excep){ }
}
```

Here is my Unit test case.

```
it('should get non dealing dates ',() => {
  component.getNonDealingDates;
  expect(component.getNonDealingDates()).toBeUndefined();
})
```

Do I need to include mock for subscribe? How can I mock for the above code?

Comment: Did you mock the `detailsService` ?

Comment: @AnuradhaGunasekara detail service is not a service is just a name which was provided will change the name

Comment: Any way if you have any services that are injected to the component you have mock them when testing.

Comment: Here I have to check how to mock u subscribe can you please help me on that

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your component looks like this.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DetailsService } from 'path/to/your/service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component-name',
  styleUrls: ['./app-your-component-name.css'],
  templateUrl: './app-your-component-name.html'
})
export class YourComponent { 

public days: any; // replace any with the correct data type.

 constructor(private detailsService: DetailsService) {}

  public getNonDealingDates() {
    try {
      this.detailsService.nonDealingdates().subscribe(
        res => {
        this.days = res
        }, error => {
          throw error;
        });
    } catch (excep) {

    }
  }
}
```

And for a class like this we can write unit test like this.

```
import { Input, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs/internal/Subject';

import { DetailsService } from 'path/to/your/service';
import { YourComponent } from 'path/to/your/component';


describe('YourComponent tests', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<YourComponent>;
    let component: YourComponent;

    let detailsService: DetailsService;
    let spyDetailsService: jasmine.SpyObj<DetailsService>;

    let subject;

    const response: any = {};

    beforeEach(async(() => {
      subject = new Subject();

      spyDetailsService = jasmine.createSpyObj('DetailsService', ['nonDealingdates']);
      spyDetailsService.nonDealingdates.and.returnValue(subject.asObservable());

      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [YourComponent],
        providers: [
          { provide: DetailsService, useValue: spyDetailsService }
        ],
        schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
      }).compileComponents().then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(YourComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;

        detailsService = TestBed.get(DetailsService);
      });
    }));

    afterEach(() => {
      subject = null;
    });

    describe('#getNonDealingDates tests', () => {
      it('Should set the days to the value returned by the detailsService.nonDealingdates()', () => {
        component.getNonDealingDates();
        subject.next(response);

        expect(component.days).toEqual(response);
      });
    });
});
```

In here I have provided a mocked service as the `DetailsService`.

`spyDetailsService = jasmine.createSpyObj('DetailsService', ['nonDealingdates']);`

I have created a spyObject using `jasmine.createSpyObject` method.

And Take a look at the providers array.

```
providers: [
          { provide: DetailsService, useValue: spyDetailsService }
        ],
```

Instead of providing the actual service I have provided the mocked object.

As your details service's `nonDealingdates` method returns a observable I am retuning a subject as an observable in the mocked service method.

```
spyDetailsService.nonDealingdates.and.returnValue(subject.asObservable());
```

And when your are testing the `getNonDealingDates` method you have to invoke
`subject.next()` with the service response as a parameter.

Comment: THanks for replying but as i told already DetailService is not a service just a name so can you please suggest how i can do this

Comment: what do you mean by *just a name*? Is it a variable? Can you add complete code for the component?

Comment: Are you sure that the `DetailsService` is not a **service** ?

Comment: Yes I added my code where how my detail service is calling

Comment: As I see you have injected your `DetailsService` to the component constructor. So you have to mock your dependencies. Just go through the code that I have provided.  And try to do the same for your component also.

Comment: I was trying create using mock but still I am getting the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179310/discussion-between-anuradha-gunasekara-and-mahadevan).